# If statement ignored JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

When I click a button, the function goes properly but my if statement is being ignored. The display may contain only 4 characters.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nummer").click(function() {

        if ($("#display").val().length > 4) {
            alert("test");
        } else {

            var nummer = $(this).text();

            $("#display").append(nummer);
        }

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="display"> </div>
<div id="toetsen">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop1">1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop2">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nummer" href="#" id="knop3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for divs

```
if ( $("#display").text().length > 4)
{
     alert("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `text` to get the inner Text of the `#display`:

```
if ($.trim($("#display").text()).length > 4) {
```

`val` is used to get the `value` of inputs.

`trim` will remove the extra spaces from beginning and end of the string.

Comment: wow, your answer is the same as mine or even better, yet somebody downvoted you

Comment: Why DownVote? Please add comments here

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()` for div , `val()` is used for Input elements...

Comment: Can you please add some color to your answer to make it useful to more people. Teach a man to fish!